# "NameError: name 'add' is not defined" - I did define it though

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

NOTE: (This is just a part of the code @furas)

I was told by my father to create a timesheet so that his employees working hours would be recorded 24/7. I am trying to make a button, a button that adds a new employee. As you can see in the code, father presses the add/"**+**" button which opens a new window, this window is has an entry widget so that father could enter the name of the new employee.
Then father would press the submit button and it is supposed to add all of the details there should be like: the name, the time in and time out buttons, for the new employee, by using the .get() function, anyways that is not the problem, I know how to do that.

The problem is:
I want to make the code look look like this, but obviously I cant becuase add wouldn't be defined. How can I get the same outcome, but different code, any ideas?

WHY = I want to take the new name and make a new employee section with it.
Hopefully you understand?
The new employee section will add another row designated for the new employee[Lets say the new name is josh, so a new row, with designated for josh will appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpa4n.png)

```
 # ADD EMPLOYEE BUTTON
add_employee_button = ttk.Button(root, text="+", command=add_employee)
add_employee_button.grid(column=6, row=1)


def submit():
    global new_employee_name
    global add_entry
    new_employee_name = add_entry.get()
    print(new_employee_name)

# SUBMIT BUTTON FOR ADD EMPLOYEE
submit_employee_entry_button = Button(add, text="SUBMIT", command=submit)
submit_employee_entry_button.pack()
```

Comment: Fix the formatting of your code, otherwise we cannot help since it is hard to know what your code is.

Comment: This is a _huge_ amount of code for what is probably a simple problem. Please try to create a [mcve] specifically for this question.

Comment: Please repost marking it as a code block (the {} symbol) not block quotes. And instead of this huge code drop, write a very small test file demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Ok, sorry for not doing before, I am new to stack overflow, and just a 10 yr old, thanks
is the reformating fine now?

Comment: you should create this button inside function `add_employee`

Comment: You need to put the creation of `submit_employee_entry_button` inside `add_employee()`.

Comment: you can't create button when window doesn't exist - and `global add` doesn't create global variable - it only inform function to use external/global variable (instead of local variable) when you do `add = ...` - and you create this variable when you do `add = Toplevel()` inside `add_employee`

Comment: what `specific reason` do you have to create it outside `add_employee` ?

Comment: I have edited the question, @furas|
for the specific reason to why i need to create it outside look back at the main question - description

Comment: first: don't change original code - now our comments don't fit to your question.

Comment: I still don't understan why you want to do outside function - but answer still is the same: you can't do it, you can't create button when window doesn't exist, Besides when you close/destroy window then it will destroy also this button and you will have to create it when you will open this window again.

Comment: Sorry!! It was just I wanted to show you what I wanted it to look like, and it wouldnt let me in the comments

Comment: I see what you want to do but I don't understand WHY. And this version simply makes no sense for me - so I can't understand why to create button when window doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, I understand better, but is there a way to open an existing window on a button press, and not create new window on a button press

Comment: you can create window at start and hide it - but for me also make no sense.

Comment: WHY = I want to take the new name and make a new employee section with it. 
Hopefully you understand?

Comment: I have edited the question, go back and look at the photo example

Comment: I understand why you want to use button but I don't understand why you want to create it outside function which creates window. You can get name and create new section even if you create button inside function after creating window. And you can keep function `submit()` in current place (outside function which create window). As for me this is only and natural method - create button inside function after creating window.

Comment: usually all problem makes that GUIs work different then console program with `input()` - `input()` waits for answer and it runs rest of code after pressing ENTER, so other elements has to be after `input()`. But widgets in GUI don't wait for answer - they only inform `mainloop` what it has to display in window. so there is no need to put button `Submit` directly after `+`

Comment: ok, but I was trying to make a type of messagebox with an entry (toplevel)
so that when he presses submit, the "messagebox would show up"
if you know what I mean

Comment: in answer I created code which opens window with `entry` and button `submit` and this button runs function which creates employee  in main window. If you need real messagebox then you can use module `tkinter.messagebox` -

Answer (score 0):

You should put this button inside functon `add_employee` and it will create it after creating window.

It has no sense to create it outside this function. GUIs work in different way than `input()` - widgets don't wait for user data but they only inform `mainloop` what it has to display in window. Mainloop starts GUI - it creates window and displays all widgets.

Here code which creates button inside function `add_employee` and it adds new employee to window. It doesn't have to be outside this function.

The only problem is that you use unique names for buttons and functions for every employee. You should use the same name for buttons `TIME IN` and `TIME OUT` and use string (ie employee's name) to keep them in dictionary.

The same problem is with function for buttons `TIME IN` and `TIME OUT` - it should be one function for `time in` and one for `time out` and they should get employee's name and row's number as parameter - you can use `lambda` to assign to `command=` function with parameters.

I didn't check rest of code but I think you could use `for`-loop to reduce some elements.

It may need also button which runs function which create excel file - at this moment it creates it before mainloop shows window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from openpyxl.styles import alignment, Alignment, Font
from openpyxl.styles.borders import Border, Side
import time as tm
from openpyxl import Workbook

# --- functions ---

def function_start(name, number):
    current_time = tm.strftime("%H:%M")
    label = Label(root, text=current_time)
    label.grid(column=5, row=3+number)
    
    start_button = data[name][0]
    
    start_button['state'] = 'disabled'
    print(f"{name}'S TIME IN: {current_time}")

def function_stop(name, number):
    current_time = tm.strftime("%H:%M")
    label = Label(root, text=current_time)
    label.grid(column=6, row=3+number)

    stop_button = data[name][1]

    stop_button['state'] = 'disabled'
    print(f"{name}'S TIME OUT: {current_time}")

def set_border(ws, cell_range, style):
    side = Side(border_style=style, color="000000")
    for row in ws[cell_range]:
        for cell in row:
            cell.border = Border(top=side, left=side, right=side, bottom=side)

def submit():
    global window_add
    global add_entry
    global new_employee_name

    name = add_entry.get()

    print(name)    

    number = len(data) + 1
    
    name_label = Label(root, text=name)

    start_button = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME IN", command=lambda n=name,i=number:function_start(n, i))
    stop_button = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME OUT", command=lambda n=name,i=number:function_stop(n, i))
    
    name_label.grid(column=0, row=3+number)
    start_button.grid(column=1, row=3+number, padx=10)
    stop_button.grid( column=2, row=3+number, padx=10)

    data[name] = [start_button, stop_button, name_label]
    
    window_add.destroy()
    
def add_employee():
    global window_add
    global add_entry
    
    window_add = Toplevel()
    window_add.title("ADD EMPLOYEE")

    add_entry = ttk.Entry(window_add)
    add_entry.pack()

    button = Button(window_add, text="SUBMIT", command=submit)
    button.pack()
    
# --- main ---

data = {}  # to keep buttons 

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("BFREE AUTOMATED TIMESHEET")
#root.geometry("10000x10000")
#root.iconbitmap("BFREE.png")

for number, name in enumerate(['JIMENA', 'GAGAN', 'CLAUDIA', 'MIRANDA']):
             
    name_label = Label(root, text=name)

    start_button = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME IN", command=lambda n=name,i=number:function_start(n, i))
    stop_button = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME OUT", command=lambda n=name,i=number:function_stop(n, i))
    
    name_label.grid(column=0, row=3+number)
    start_button.grid(column=1, row=3+number, padx=10)
    stop_button.grid( column=2, row=3+number, padx=10)

    data[name] = [start_button, stop_button, name_label]
    
# ADD EMPLOYEE BUTTON
add_employee_button = ttk.Button(root, text="+", command=add_employee)
add_employee_button.grid(column=6, row=1)

set_border(ws, 'A1:U1', 'thin')
set_border(ws, 'A1:v6', "medium")

thin_border = Border(left=Side(style='thin'),
                     right=Side(style='thin'),
                     top=Side(style='thin'),
                     bottom=Side(style='thin'))


# EMPLOYEE NAMES
ws['A3'] = "GAGAN"
ws["a3"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws['a4'] = "CLAUDIA"
ws["a4"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws['a5'] = "MIRANDA"
ws["a5"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws['A6'] = "JIMENA"
ws["a6"].font = Font(bold=True)

# DAYS OF THE WEEK
ws.merge_cells("b1:c1")
currentCell = ws["B1"]
currentCell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
ws["b1"] = "MON"
ws["b1"].font = Font(bold=True)

ws.merge_cells("d1:e1")
currentCell = ws["d1"]
currentCell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
ws["d1"] = "TUES"
ws["d1"].font = Font(bold=True)

ws.merge_cells("f1:g1")
currentCell = ws["f1"]
currentCell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
ws["f1"] = "WED"
ws["f1"].font = Font(bold=True)

ws.merge_cells("h1:i1")
currentCell = ws["h1"]
currentCell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
ws["h1"] = "THUR"
ws["h1"].font = Font(bold=True)

ws.merge_cells("j1:k1")
currentCell = ws["j1"]
currentCell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
ws["j1"] = "FRI"
ws["j1"].font = Font(bold=True)

ws.merge_cells("l1:m1")
currentCell = ws["l1"]
currentCell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
ws["l1"] = "MON"
ws["l1"].font = Font(bold=True)

ws.merge_cells("n1:o1")
currentCell = ws["n1"]
currentCell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
ws["n1"] = "TUES"
ws["n1"].font = Font(bold=True)

ws.merge_cells("p1:q1")
currentCell = ws["p1"]
currentCell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
ws["p1"] = "WED"
ws["p1"].font = Font(bold=True)

ws.merge_cells("r1:s1")
currentCell = ws["r1"]
currentCell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
ws["r1"] = "THUR"
ws["r1"].font = Font(bold=True)

ws.merge_cells("t1:u1")
currentCell = ws["t1"]
currentCell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
ws["t1"] = "FRI"
ws["t1"].font = Font(bold=True)

ws.merge_cells("v1:v2")
currentCell = ws["v1"]
currentCell.alignment = Alignment(vertical="center")
ws["V1"] = "TOTAL:"
ws["V1"].font = Font(bold=True)

# TIME IN AND TIME OUT CELLS
ws["b2"] = "TIME IN"
ws["B2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["c2"] = "TIME OUT"
ws["c2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["d2"] = "TIME IN"
ws["d2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["e2"] = "TIME OUT"
ws["e2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["f2"] = "TIME IN"
ws["f2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["g2"] = "TIME OUT"
ws["g2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["h2"] = "TIME IN"
ws["h2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["i2"] = "TIME OUT"
ws["i2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["j2"] = "TIME IN"
ws["j2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["k2"] = "TIME OUT"
ws["k2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["l2"] = "TIME IN"
ws["l2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["m2"] = "TIME OUT"
ws["m2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["n2"] = "TIME IN"
ws["n2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["o2"] = "TIME OUT"
ws["o2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["p2"] = "TIME IN"
ws["p2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["q2"] = "TIME OUT"
ws["q2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["r2"] = "TIME IN"
ws["r2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["s2"] = "TIME OUT"
ws["s2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["T2"] = "TIME IN"
ws["t2"].font = Font(bold=True)
ws["U2"] = "TIME OUT"
ws["u2"].font = Font(bold=True)
 
wb.save("BFREE.xlsx")
mainloop()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Version which uses `for`-loops to generate EXCEL.

It also adds values from buttons `TIME IN` and `TIME OUT` to column `MON`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from openpyxl.styles import alignment, Alignment, Font
from openpyxl.styles.borders import Border, Side
import time as tm
from openpyxl import Workbook

# --- functions ---

def function_start(name, number):
    current_time = tm.strftime("%H:%M")
    label = tk.Label(root, text=current_time)
    label.grid(column=5, row=3+number)
    
    start_button = data[name]['start']
    
    start_button['state'] = 'disabled'
    print(f"{name}'S TIME IN: {current_time}")
    
    data[name]['time_in'] = current_time

def function_stop(name, number):
    current_time = tm.strftime("%H:%M")
    label = tk.Label(root, text=current_time)
    label.grid(column=6, row=3+number)

    stop_button = data[name]['stop']

    stop_button['state'] = 'disabled'
    print(f"{name}'S TIME OUT: {current_time}")

    data[name]['time_out'] = current_time

def set_border(ws, cell_range, style):
    side = Side(border_style=style, color="000000")
    for row in ws[cell_range]:
        for cell in row:
            cell.border = Border(top=side, left=side, right=side, bottom=side)

def submit():
    global window_add
    global add_entry
    global new_employee_name

    name = add_entry.get()

    print(name)    

    number = len(data) + 1
    
    name_label = tk.Label(root, text=name)

    start_button = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME IN", command=lambda n=name,i=number:function_start(n, i))
    stop_button = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME OUT", command=lambda n=name,i=number:function_stop(n, i))
    
    name_label.grid(column=0, row=3+number)
    start_button.grid(column=1, row=3+number, padx=10)
    stop_button.grid( column=2, row=3+number, padx=10)

    data[name] = {"start": start_button, "stop": stop_button, 'time_in': '', 'time_out': ''}
    
    window_add.destroy()
    
def add_employee():
    global window_add
    global add_entry
    
    window_add = tk.Toplevel()
    window_add.title("ADD EMPLOYEE")

    add_entry = ttk.Entry(window_add)
    add_entry.pack()

    button = ttk.Button(window_add, text="SUBMIT", command=submit)
    button.pack()
    
def generate_workbook():
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    number = len(data)
    
    set_border(ws, 'A1:U1', 'thin')
    set_border(ws, f'A1:v{2+number}', "medium")
    
    thin_border = Border(left=Side(style='thin'),
                         right=Side(style='thin'),
                         top=Side(style='thin'),
                         bottom=Side(style='thin'))
    

    # EMPLOYEE NAMES
    for number, name in enumerate(data.keys()):
        ws[f'A{3+number}'] = name
        ws[f'A{3+number}'].font = Font(bold=True)
    
    # DAYS OF THE WEEK
    days = [
        ('B','C','MON'),
        ('D','E','TUES'),
        ('F','G','WED'),
        ('H','I','THUR'),
        ('J','K','FRI'),
        ('L','M','MON'),
        ('N','O','TUES'),
        ('P','Q','WED'),
        ('R','S','THUR'),
        ('T','U','FRI'),
    ]

    for x, y, name in days:
        ws.merge_cells(f"{x}1:{y}1")
        currentCell = ws[f"{x}1"]
        currentCell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
        ws[f"{x}1"] = name
        ws[f"{x}1"].font = Font(bold=True)
    
    for number, (name, item) in enumerate(data.items()):
        ws[f"B{3+number}"] = item['time_in']
        ws[f"C{3+number}"] = item['time_out']
        
    ws.merge_cells("v1:v2")
    currentCell = ws["v1"]
    currentCell.alignment = Alignment(vertical="center")
    ws["V1"] = "TOTAL:"
    ws["V1"].font = Font(bold=True)
    
    # TIME IN AND TIME OUT CELLS
    for col in ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J', 'L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T']:
        ws[f"{col}2"] = "TIME IN"
        ws[f"{col}2"].font = Font(bold=True)
        
    for col in ['C', 'E', 'G', 'I', 'K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S', 'U']:
        ws[f"{col}2"] = "TIME OUT"
        ws[f"{col}2"].font = Font(bold=True)
     
    wb.save("BFREE.xlsx")
    
    messagebox.showinfo('Info', 'File generated')
    
# --- main ---

data = {}  # to keep buttons and values

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("BFREE AUTOMATED TIMESHEET")
#root.geometry("10000x10000")
#root.iconbitmap("BFREE.png")

for number, name in enumerate(['JIMENA', 'GAGAN', 'CLAUDIA', 'MIRANDA']):
             
    name_label = tk.Label(root, text=name)

    start_button = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME IN", command=lambda n=name,i=number:function_start(n, i))
    stop_button = ttk.Button(root, text="TIME OUT", command=lambda n=name,i=number:function_stop(n, i))
    
    name_label.grid(column=0, row=3+number)
    start_button.grid(column=1, row=3+number, padx=10)
    stop_button.grid( column=2, row=3+number, padx=10)

    data[name] = {"start": start_button, "stop": stop_button, 'time_in': '', 'time_out': ''}
    
# ADD EMPLOYEE BUTTON
add_employee_button = ttk.Button(root, text="+", command=add_employee)
add_employee_button.grid(column=6, row=1)

# GENERATE EXCEL BUTTON
generate_button = ttk.Button(root, text="To Excel", command=generate_workbook)
generate_button.grid(column=7, row=1)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I added version which generates Excel using for-loops and values from buttons `TIME IN`, `TIME OUT`